# PDO passing params as array fails

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

Can someone explain why the commented line below works fine as a regular query, but fails when I try to pass it with a prepare statement?

(all code in one file)

```
<?php
class Log {

    public $id;
    public $sensor;
    public $reading;

    public function getRow() {
        return $this->id.' '.$this->sensor.' '.$this->reading;
    }
}

try 
{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=homelog", "xxx", "yyy");
    //$rs = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM logs WHERE id=1"); //WORKS FINE
    //PREPARE
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM logs WHERE id= :x");
    $arr=array(':x'=>'1');
    $rs=$stmt->execute($arr);
    //END PREPARE

    $rs->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, new Log());
    foreach($rs as $l)
    {
        echo $l->getRow().'<br />';
    } 
    $dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

error log reporting (thanks to the commentors):

```
[Wed Feb 24 00:05:59 2016] [error] [client 66.55.xxx.yyy] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setFetchMode() on a non-object in /var/www/PiServer/testObj.php on line 24
```

updated code in response to answers:

```
....
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=homelog", "root", "root");
    //$rs = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM logs WHERE id=1"); //WORKS FINE
    //PREPARE
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM logs WHERE id= :x");
    $arr=array(':x'=>'1');
    $rs=$stmt->execute($arr); //bool result value
    //END PREPARE
    $ret=$stmt->fetchObject("Log")
    foreach($ret as $l)
    {
        echo $l->getRow().'<br />';
    } 
    $dbh = null;
.....
```

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: There isnt an error message (not that I could find). No page content, and no output to console. Im very new to PHP so if I should check somewhere else please let me know. Im happy to post something else if needed.

Comment: Please refer this  : http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/pdo-prepare-execute

Comment: Add the statement `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your code, and check your server's `error.log` file. Also, review the documentation on PDO, specifically the page on [PDOStatement::execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php).

Comment: I updated the post with the error log, but that makes no sense to me.... How could the script find `setFetchMode()` before but not during the prepared statement?

Comment: The documentation page I linked will reveal *why* you're getting that particular error. It involves precisely what is being stored in `$rs`.

Comment: I am reading that now.... As far as I can tell I am following example 2 formatting perfectly..... Can you explain what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PDOStatement::execute()` doesn't return a result set, it just returns a boolean indicating whether the query succeeded. Your code then tries to call `setFetchMode()` on that boolean, which of course is not valid.

In order to get the result of the query you need to call one of the `PDOStatement::fetch*` methods. What I suspect you want to do is

```
while ($l = $stmt->fetchObject("Log"))
{
    echo $l->getRow().'<br />';
}
```

which also eliminates the need to call `setFetchMode()`.

(I confess I've never used `fetchObject()`, so I may not have the syntax exactly right.)

Comment: Close. You don't want to use `foreach`; that's for walking arrays. What you can do is condition a `while` on the result of `fetch`, which returns **`false`** when it runs out of records. I've expanded on my answer above to illustrate.

Comment: I wound up having to use `$l=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "Log");`